# Does puppet agent -t use puppet.conf?

Tags: puppet

I plan to use puppet via a cron job.

In my `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` I have:

```
splay = true                                                                                                                                                             
splaylimit = 30
```

In my cron job I run `puppet agent -t` which doesn't use splay.

Should the command be using splay here? Server url is set in the same `puppet.conf` file and that doesn't seem to have a problem.

I also tried `splaylimit = 30m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In short yes, but ...***

My problem was due to not fully understanding the `-t` aka `--test` flag.

> **--test** Enable the most common options used for testing. These are 'onetime', 'verbose', 'no-daemonize', 'no-usecacheonfailure',
>   'detailed-exitcodes', 'no-splay', 'show_diff', and
>   'no-use_cached_catalog'.

As `--test` specifically implies no-splay the values in `puppet.conf` are overridden.

*Side note: Splay seems to be defined in seconds e.g. 300 = 5 minutes, 600 = 10 minutes. Minutes and hours can defined as well 5m, 10m, 1hr, 2hr, ect.*

Comment: Yes, if you do not specify a unit then the splay time is interpreted as a number of seconds.  That is [documented](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/configuration.html#splay), and on older versions of Puppet, it was the only alternative.